# Getting values from Pristine form controls in Angular2

Tags: angular

In the app I am working on, depending on permissions, some users get a list of choices and others are restricted. IE Admins can look at all the stores, regular users can only look at their own. I have the following markup:

```
<p *ngIf="storeList.length > 1">
    <label>Store:</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="storeNumber">
        <option></option>
        <option *ngFor="let store of storeList" [value]="store.id">{{ store.name }} (#{{ store.internal_id }})</option>
    </select>
</p>

<input *ngIf="storeList.length <= 1 type="text" [(ngModel)]="storeNumber" ngFor="let store of storeList" value="{{ store.id }}">
```

Here is the relevant controller details:

```
submitFabricReservation() {
    let base = this;
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let url = `http://laravel.localhost/fabrics/reservation`;
    let data = {
        cloth: this.cloth,
        garment_type: this.garmentType,
        consumer_name: this.consumerName,
        store_number: this.storeNumber
    };

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), { headers: headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(function(data) {
            base.messageService.unshift(data.json());
            base.modal.dismiss();
        });
}
```

It works fine. The text box appears when it should and has the correct ID as its value. ***BUT*** in the controller function, this.storeNumber is undefined. If I manually edit the value in the text box, then the controller receives the value and this.storeNumber is set to whatever I typed into the input box. It *seems* like the model only gets updated when there is an change event, or, that angular ignores things when it is still pristine.

I can see a few way around the problem, I don't know how to do all of them, however. Nor do I know which (if any!) would be the proper angular way to do things. I can:

1. Set the this.storeNumber in the http callback (I know how to do this)
2. Force a change event to fire on the input (Where and when would I do this?)
3. Set an id on the element (#storeNumber) and forcibly get the value that way

I'm not sure if any of these are the correct option though. This seems like something that would come up often enough. I must be missing something cause it seems like it should be easy. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the right option. That's what binding is about: the single-point of truth is the model. The view just displays (and allows modifying) the model. So, if you want a text field to have a given value, you don't set it in the view. You set it in the model, and since the input is bound to the model, it displays its value.

Note that if you had several elements in the store list, you would ask yourself how to set or remove the selected attribute on the option which has the selected storeNumber. Well, you don't need to, because once again, the select is bound to storeNumber. So, simply setting storeNumber in the model will make the corresponding option selected.